# Why is Activity Monitor showing two different memory values for the same process?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, spotlight, activity-monitor, virtual-memory

In Activity Monitor, I am getting two different values for the same process, mds_stores.

[image: The values in question]

The usage was around 4 GB an hour ago in the list and the window. It was high because I was reindexing my Spotlight results, because I had to disable and reenable it.

I am on a MacBook Air (11-inch, Early 2015) configured with a i5 5250U.

Comment: If you control click in the activity monitor windows on the text memory - can you add all the various "flavors / counts" of memory and see if the values from the first window are just hidden on the second window?

Comment: Just did that, the real, private, and shared memory are the same from the main window as the mds_stores window